# Access SQL query with JOIN and a COUNT statement not counting anything

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have two tables in MS Access. One for planets and one for the type of star it orbits.

I want to get a count of the planets per star type...so something like:

```
+----------+--------------------+
| StarType | PlanetsPerStarType |
+----------+--------------------+
| A        |                  4 |
| B        |                  1 |
| C        |                  7 |
+----------+--------------------+
```

So I wrote this SQL query:

```
SELECT StarType, COUNT(PlanetName) AS PlanetsPerStarType
FROM Planets AS p
LEFT JOIN StarClass AS s ON p.sid = s.sid
GROUP BY starType, PlanetName
```

But it just lists all the planets and a `1` for all the star types, it doesn't really count at all.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: `PlanetName` shouldn't be in the `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By grouping by the `starType` **and** the `PlanetName`, the count is returning the number of records in each `starType` & `PlanetName` combination, which, unless you have more than one planet of the same name orbiting your star, will always be one.

For example, given the data:

```
+-----------+------------------+
| StarType  |    PlanetName    |
+-----------+------------------+
| G2V       | Mars             |
| G2V       | Earth            |
| G2V       | Venus            |
| Red Dwarf | Omicron Persei 8 |
| Red Dwarf | Vergon 6         |
+-----------+------------------+
```

Grouping by `StarType` **and** `PlanetName` will yield exactly the same data, since there are no repeating `StarType` and `PlanetName` combinations which would be consolidated into a group.

As such, the SQL code:

```sql
select t.StarType, count(t.PlanetName) as Planets
from YourTable t
group by t.StarType, t.PlanetName
```

Would yield:

```
+-----------+---------+
| StarType  | Planets |
+-----------+---------+
| G2V       |       1 |
| G2V       |       1 |
| G2V       |       1 |
| Red Dwarf |       1 |
| Red Dwarf |       1 |
+-----------+---------+
```

Since each group contains exactly **one** record.

If, instead, we group only by `StarType`, the `Count` aggregate function will return the number of records associated with each `StarType`:

```sql
select t.StarType, count(t.PlanetName) as Planets
from YourTable t
group by t.StarType
```

```
+-----------+---------+
| StarType  | Planets |
+-----------+---------+
| G2V       |       3 |
| Red Dwarf |       2 |
+-----------+---------+
```